# Read ViewBag in javascript generating errors

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, view, viewbag

I tried many ways to get the value of a ViewBag in Javascript, but all showed errors. I have a view and a js file.

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" data-myValue="@ViewBag.PrimerNombre" />
//Undefined
var myVal = $("#myInput").data("myValue");
alert(myVal);

<input type="hidden" id="customInput" data-value="@ViewBag.PrimerNombre" />
//Cannot read property value of null
var customVal = $("#customInput").data("value");
alert(customVal);

//Cannot read property value of null
<script type="text/javascript">
   var myJsVariable = '@ViewBag.PrimerNombre' 
</script>

//Show warning is not defined
$(document).ready(function() {
                showWarning('@ViewBag.Message');
});

//Unrecognized expression #@(ViewBag.PrimerNombre)
var x = $('#' + '@(ViewBag.PrimerNombre)').val();         

//Cannot read property value of null
var myValue = document.getElementById("@(ViewBag.PrimerNombre)").value;
```

I tried all, one by one, there is one part ot the view that matchs a part in the javascript file, i put the errors above, if you know a way that really works please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found that the code that was after in my js, some code i copied and that i needed to adapt was the one causing the error